# label not getting applied in sqlalchemy queries

Tags: sqlalchemy

i am quite new to sqlalchemy. i have the following code:

```
table = tables[self.table]
field_list = []
if self.fields is not None:
    for k, v in self.fields.items():
        one_field = getattr(table, k)
        if not isinstance(one_field, QueryableAttribute):
            raise InvalidFieldError("Invalid field for specified table: %s" %field)
        one_field.label(v)
        field_list.append(one_field)
if len(field_list) > 0:
    query = session.query(*field_list)
else:
    query = session.query(table)
```

note that `self.fields` is the following dictionary:

```
"fields" : {
    "first_name" : "First",
    "last_name" : "Last"
},
```

`table` is of type

so in the line `one_field.label(v)`, `one_field` is of type `sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute`. Therefore, I thought that calling `label(v)` on it would effectively label that column so that when I get the SqlAlchemy Query object, and I do this:

```
for row in alchemy_query_object:
    row_dict = row._asdict()
    print(row_dict)
```

I should expect to see that the columns have been renamed with the label. However, this is not the case.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: you should probably do `field_list.append(one_field.label(v))` perhaps?

Comment: jesus christ! i feel so stupid now!! thank you!!